# Not receiving push notifications for iCloud 2-factor authentication

Tags: icloud, security, notifications, two-step-authentication

I followed the instructions on [this sixcolors.com blog post](https://sixcolors.com/post/2016/07/doing-the-two-step-switching-to-apples-two-factor-authentication/) to disable and re-enable 2-factor authentication on my iCloud account in order to upgrade to the "newer" version.

However, now when I attempt to log in on the web or on a device, I no longer receive a push notification with a 2-factor authentication code on my devices.  I am able to receive a text message or generate a code from Settings but I no longer receive an automatic push notification with the code.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, or have any idea what I could do to fix it?  I tried disabling and re-enabling 2-factor authentication on my iCloud account once more but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you running iOS 10 on any device connected to your iCloud account? There seems to be a beta bug at the moment with 2-factor auth if you have an iOS 10 device registered on your Apple ID.

Comment: @grgarside No, I have not installed iOS 10 or macOS Sierra on any of my devices.  My iPhone is on iOS 9 and my mac is on El Capitan.  Thanks for the info though.

Comment: It appears that 2-factor authentication push notifications are now delivered to my iPhone, a few hours after enabling it.  So this issue seems to be resolved.